# Number of partitions of a positive integer with largest part not exceeding k

Tags: integer-partitions

What is the number of partitions of $n\in \mathbb{N}$ so that the largest part is at most $k$?

I tried it for a few small cases, but I am unable to find a general way.

Comment: You need to be more specific. For instance, does, $k\in\Bbb N$?

Comment: Did you read the wikipedia article about partitions ? This variant should be mentioned somewhere.